# Pass search word to template in Drupal Solr search

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Can I get the searched word passed to the search-results.tpl.php template? I am using Drupal and Solr search.

Answer (score 0):

try saving it searched text in a GLOBAL variable like $variables['makeurown'] and then access it in the template file. It should work.